# jQuery custom accordition, close other opened li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `<ul>` that works like an accordition.

- When I click on one, it opens.
- When I click another one, all the opened accorditions must close

Being in the loop over all `<li>`, I no longer have acces to this, I have tried passing it as an argument to the function but it doesn't work

```
$('.form-trigger').on('click', function() {
      var parent_li = $(this).closest('li');
      var parent_ul = $(this).closest('.form-list');

      console.log(parent_li);
      var current_li = parent_li


      parent_ul.find('li').each(function(current_li) {
        if( $(this).hasClass('active') && $(this) != current_li ) {
           $(this).removeClass('active');
           $(this).find('.inner__form-list').slideToggle();
        }

        } );

        parent_li.toggleClass('active');
        parent_li.find('.inner__form-list').slideToggle();
        parent_li.find('span').toggleClass('close-form-item');

    });
```

`.form-trigger` -> it's the `<a>` tag, it gets tot the parent `li` and adds class `active`

Comment: just change `function(current_li)` to `function()` and it should be fine and add `;` after `var current_li = parent_li`

Comment: is the help useful?

Answer (score 0):

Just change

`parent_ul.find('li').each(function(current_li) {`

to

`parent_ul.find('li').each(function() {`

and `current_li` will be visible inside your `.each()` loop as it is in the scope.

add a `;` at the end of `var current_li = parent_li` too.

I hope the other part of the code is doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  $('.form-trigger').on('click', function() {
>       var parent_li = $(this).closest('li');
>       var parent_ul = $(this).closest('.form-list');
>
>   console.log(parent_li);
>   var current_li = parent_li;
>
>   parent_li.siblings().removeClass('active').find('.inner__form-list').slideUp();
>
>     parent_li.toggleClass('active');
>     parent_li.find('.inner__form-list').slideToggle();
>     parent_li.find('span').toggleClass('close-form-item');
> });
> ```

Using .siblings() worked, but thank you for your answers.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this.

```
$('.form-trigger').on('click', function() {
      var parent_li = $(this).closest('li');
      var parent_ul = $(this).closest('.form-list');

      console.log(parent_li);
      var current_li = parent_li

      var self = this;
      parent_ul.find('li').each(function(current_li) {
        if( $(self).hasClass('active') && $(self) != current_li ) {
           $(self).removeClass('active');
           $(self).find('.inner__form-list').slideToggle();
        }

        } );

        parent_li.toggleClass('active');
        parent_li.find('.inner__form-list').slideToggle();
        parent_li.find('span').toggleClass('close-form-item');

    });
```

That is store the value of this in a variable (usually devs name it self) and use it within the loop.